# How to add custom format specifier to fmt

Tags: fmt

I'm trying to replace a custom type safe format function with calls to fmt.  The current implementation supports a 'u' specifier, which prints values as unsigned irregardless of their sign.  I would like to add the same functionality to my calls to fmt::vformat.

I tried just substituting 'd' for instances of 'u' but this will not print negative values properly.

I need to know how to inject a custom integer specifier that invokes the current implementation with the value casted to an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a new format specifier to a built-in formatter so I recommend just converting to `unsigned`:

```cpp
int answer = -42;
fmt::print("{}", unsigned(answer)); // prints 4294967254
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5bdtgA